# How to fix string validation issue caused by DecimalFormat.parse() behaving differently in pre-android7 and android 7?

Tags: java, android, android-7.0-nougat

```
    private static double javaNumberFormat(String value, Locale locale) throws ParseException {
            ParsePosition parsePosition = new ParsePosition(0);
            DecimalFormat numFormat = (java.text.DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale);
            Number number = numFormat.parse(value, parsePosition);

            if(number == null || parsePosition.getIndex() != value.length())
                throw new ParseException("Invalid input", parsePosition.getIndex());

            return number.doubleValue();
        }
```

In pre-android 7, When you pass the string "123 45" as "value" to the above method, it throws parse exception because the DecimalFormat.parse() returns null for "123 45".  In Android 7, the method returns "12345" because DecimalFormat.parse() returns "12345".

The reason for the above behavior is because of the following migration by android team.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/icu4j-framework.html#migration

I am looking for alternatives to DecimalFormat that can parse the given string and that solution should also consider locale information.  Double.parseDouble is working for me but it doesn't take locale into consideration.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are, but if you are parsing Money, then make use of the `Joda Money` library https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-money